# Failed to open backingstore in database because not enough space for domain error in chrome of ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, indexeddb, angular-service-worker

**Steps to reproduce the problem:**

1. 1.Application Which using indexed DB and Service worker
2. Upload few images.
3. Keep the browser open and use the application next day then repeat the same steps.

[image]

**Problem Description:**

In iPad chrome, we are facing "Faild to open backingstore domain not enough space for domain" error, When we are keeep open the browser and using next day. It is an angular application with Indexed DB and Service worker as well. upload the few images in ipad and it will stored in indexed DB as "Arraybuffer" and keep open and try to do the upload in next day then this issue happen.

Comment: Can you please provide a specific question instead of only stating the problem. What help are you hoping to receive?

Comment: Thanks @Josh, In iPad, when we are kept open the browser and using next day. It is an angular application with Indexed DB and Service worker as well. App is freezing and in console an exception "Failed to open backingstore in database because not enough space for domain" was thrown.